# Need to use data from a txt on an android app

Tags: c#, android, text

I'm trying to make an app that, either connects to my PC database and get data or use data from a txt file that is on the android phone. I have read that to make a sql/android conection.  I need a web server and so i think i could try to make the app read data from a txt located on the phone and then use it. Any ideas or info on how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "txt" located on your phone? You can surely make a local database using sqlite and perform CRUD operations on it. Also, you need a web server when you want to store your data online so that it is available across devices and even technologies.

Comment: You will need to use fileInputStream / fileOutputStream to open and read the file.